# Sending get request using python urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I've got the following 2 approaches of using python urllib in order to send get request to remote server :

the first approach defines the url and the params in a single string and send it :

```
loginurl = "https://myloginserver.com/login-index?a=a&b=b&c=c"
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(loginurl, context=ctx)
xmlprelogin = resp.read()
```

The second approach defines the params and the url separately and create an `urllib.request.Request` out of those two ingredients. than use the request object instead of string with urlopen.

```
loginurl = "https://myloginserver.com/login-index
params = "a=a&b=b&c=c".encode()
 
req = urllib.request.Request(loginurl, data=params)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req, context=ctx)
```

I wonder if those 2 approaches are equivalent ? and if not, what are the differences

thanks

Comment: Not really.  If your parameters are fixed and don't use any strange characters, then go ahead and do things the simple way.  If your parameters won't be known until run time, or may contain characters that need to be encoded, let urllib take care of it.

Comment: One puts the data in the URL and the other puts it in the body of the request

Comment: @JiříBaum, so does it means that the first one is sending GET and the second one is for POST requests ?

Comment: That's how you'd normally use it, yes